# User customizable template engine with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I wanna create an application which will allow users to customize their layout or to develop their own template and install just like how [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) does. I wanna achieve this with [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)! Is this a solved problem in rails or something I need to develop from scratch? Any resource of how to achieve this will much be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main languages are Liquid and Mustache. There's a bit about the topic here: [Rails End-User Templating Engines: Liquid vs Mustache vs. Others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129925/rails-end-user-templating-engines-liquid-vs-mustache-vs-others)